# Does AFTER mean always after the number said?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

my question is does always AFTER for example 3 something means that the 4th is the thing?

I give you two examples:

> If you had 3 girls and fourth girl gave you first kiss. After how many
>   girls did you get your first kiss? After 3 girls I got my first kiss or after 2?

Similar example:

> If you found some thing you have been looking for in third drawer.
>   After how many drawers you found it? I found it after 3 drawers or 2
>   drawers?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I'm not sure if it is productive to ask about the same thing several times - for example, see [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/127468/until-5th-car-does-it-include-or-not-include-it) and [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/128362/after-how-many-usage-of-after)

Comment: Well,  in this context, it's not quite appropriate to say you "had three girls".  "I have three girls" generally means you have three *female children*.  Instead you could say, "I had three **girlfriends**, but I got my first kiss from the fourth."   But, yes, it's after *three* that you got the desired result.

Comment: Andrew so the 3rd girl was finally the one that gave me kiss? If I say after?

Answer (score 0):

To build on @Andrew's comment.  "After" always draws a line between the time before an action and the action itself.  Thus,

> If you met four girls and the fourth girl gave you a kiss, after how
>   many girls did you get a kiss?  Answer: three.

He's also right about using the word "had."  When applied to people — especially females — it has a, um..., well... (*cough*) somewhat sexual meaning.

Comment: and how do you say if the first girl gave me kiss? It seems to me illogical to say after 3. Because AFTER I had the 4th girl I got the kiss. before i didnt have her so i could not get the kiss but after 4girls i go the kiss. because the fourth gave me

Comment: If you met four girls and the first girl gave you a kiss, after how many girls did you get a kiss?  Answer: zero.  The kiss occcured before all other actions, therefore it occured "after" nothing.  Try it this way, "After three girls passed me by, a fourth girl gave me a kiss."  An awkward way to ask the question can be answered the way you're looking for.  "Four girls entered the room and the fourth girl gave me a kiss.  After how many girls entered the room did I receive my kiss?  Answer: four"  This works because we're no longer counting girls.  We're counting entrances.